# How can I setup a "blessed" repository in GitHub that the owner can also fork?

Tags: github

I want a main repository that every team member forks. Every team member would then make pull requests to the main repository from their development forks. My problem is that it doesn't seem like I can fork my own repository or make pull requests from non-forked cloned repos.

Main repository
My fork <- Can't fork my own repository?
Bob's fork
Jeff's fork

Is there a way to achieve this setup on GitHub? Aside from just developing on my own branch on the main repository, my initial thought is to have another account to hold the main repository that my development account can fork from, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Create an [organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations).

Comment: Awesome, making one now. Thanks.